# Move around background/canvas effect

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

can anyone tell me what the background effect on dexternavy.com is called?

I want the same effect, that follows the mouse around the canvas. But I do not know what to search for.

Comment: It's called 'parallax', and the version of it implemented on that site is incredibly annoying to use.

Comment: Also be aware that the way things are moving will be upsetting for users with some disabilities, and it can be a battery-flattener if the user's device is not very high powered graphics-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction. I now have this code, that works fine when you use mouse move. But how can I make it work on touch devices, so I can drag around the canvas instead?

If you go to the same website as before dexternavy.com on a iPad. I want to move/drag around the same way.

```
    $('.index').mousemove(function (e) {
        parallax(e, this, 1);
        
    });

function parallax(e, target, layer) {
    var layer_coeff = 10 / layer;
    var x = ($(window).width() - target.offsetWidth) / 2 - (e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    var y = ($(window).height() - target.offsetHeight) / 2 - (e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2)) / layer_coeff;
    $(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });

};
```